# datadog monitor add multiple resources metric in a single monitor

Tags: performance, monitoring, datadog

I am creating a single monitor and trying to monitor a bunch of resources/endpoints.

[image]

So that if the alert condition matches for either of these resources, then alert is triggered.

But since I've added other 3 resources , i.e. b, c and d there is no alert notifications triggered.

I feel like I'm adding these wrong way.

How I can I add proper formula for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include them all in the same group and use OR and AND conditions

https://docs.datadoghq.com/metrics/advanced-filtering/#boolean-filtered-query-examples

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).